# Google Sheet - Prices Chart Presentation

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

For a same product I would like to display the various prices on the same line using Google Sheet Chart.

Prices I have
18.5
20.9
21.2
17.5
15.8
21.8
22.0
25.3
27.3
32.8
avg: 22.34 min: 15.82 max: 32.80

How I would like to display it:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data in a scheme similar to the attached screenshot, then apply "insert chart", then change the chart type to "Stacked Bar", and apply data labels to every series.

Then if you insist to have the exact graphic result, you can change the colors to gray for all series (unfortunately that requires as many clicks as there are series) and selectively turn off the data labels for all except min, max and avg series (again, I'm not sure if it's possible to do automatically).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to add automatically the average in the chart ?